# "SQL Server Compact 2008" including spatial support

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I've read somewhere that there will be a "SQL Server Compact 2008" including spatial support but now that I search for it, I can't find it anywhere. For example, there's nothing on https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/content/content.aspx?ContentID=5470 regarding the compact version.

Does anyone know what the scoop is?

I have a situation here, i have created WPF application with SQL Compact edition database , now i want to store some spatial data in it. I am using google maps and want to use the geography data type which is not supported in CE. Now, what should be the best approach i should follow, should i use the express edition but then how will i encrypt the data in db / make it safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the Geography data in an "image" column in the SQL Server Compact db, no support for Geography. You can alos encrypty the SQL Server Compact db (as you probably know already)

Comment: Thank you for replying ! i will test with image data type and reply my findings!

Answer (score 0):

On [this page here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx), you can read all about the new release of SQL Server Compact Edition v4.0 - however, I don't see any mention of the SQL Server 2008 spatial datatypes being supported.

Comment: Hi marc, v4.0 is specifically for ASP.Net apps as mentioned in MS Documents. So, v4.0 is of no use o me as iam working on WPF App.

Comment: @Gurpreet Singh: SQL CE 4.0 has special enhancements to make it more useful in ASP.NET, but you can **absolutely** also use it for WPF apps!!